# C# - Se puede hacer un list de struct? Como se declara?

Tags: c#, lista, struct

Se puede hacer un list de struct? Como se declara? Como se añadiria o borraría un elemento?, Gracias.

Lo que pretendo hacer es algo como:

```
    List<T_POC> DatosActu= new List<DatosActu>();

    public struct DatosActu
    {

        public string Color;
        public DateTime Time;
        public double Altura;
        public string Categoria;

    }
```

Comment: Lo importante es que definas bien si lo que necesitas es un `struct` o un `class` pero puedes hacer exactamente lo mismo con ambos. Por el código que muestras parece que es correcto el `struct`, pero igual te dejo una referencia de SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942721/structs-versus-classes

Answer (score 1):

Por supuesto que se puede hacer un List de una estructura. Tanto la declaración como el añadir elementos se hace exactamente igual que con cualquier otra lista:

```
List<DatosActu> DatosActuList = new List<DatosActu>(); //Definición de la lista

//Añado dos elementos a la lista
DatosActuList.Add(new DatosActu() { Color = "Rojo", Time = DateTime.Now, Altura = 2, Categoria = "categoria" });
DatosActuList.Add(new DatosActu() { Color = "Azul", Time = DateTime.Now, Altura = 5, Categoria = "categoria2" });

//Borrado de elementos
DatosActuList.RemoveAt(0); //Borro elemento por indice
DatosActuList.Remove(DatosActuList.Where(x => x.Color == "Azul").FirstOrDefault()); //Borro por color
```

Comment: Que gran respuesta, soluciono el problema. Como lo hariamos para insertar un nuevo valor en un campo del struct en una celda del list donde ya existe un valor? Gracias.